# How can I run Windows bash without being root?

Tags: windows, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there a way to create a user in the new Windows 10 implementation of bash so that I'm not running it as root, without having to create a different user account in the Windows 10 system? I want to use Windows as an administrator with my normal user account but when I launch bash I want it to launch into an account other than the default account, which I'm guessing is automatically root (in the Linux subsystem) since it's the administrator account (in the Windows system).

Comment: I don't know anything about windows bash so this isn't an answer per-se. But if it's anything like linux you would do `su - [user]` to switch user. You would be prompted for the password of the user to switch to. If you wanted to do something as root once you would `sudo [command]`. This will prompt the user for their own password, but only users in to `sudoers` file can `sudo`.

Comment: While you're at it you should also turn off the AV stuff that's slowing  your PC and get rid of the password. Since you only use the admin account, why bother?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WSL is specially designed not to compromise the normal Windows security, and it is (currently) "client-only". Thus, the "root" inside a WSL session is just simulation to make things look more real for stuff you run in the "Linux" environment. From the Windows point of view, root in WSL is the same user which launched the WSL. If this user is an elevated admin, the WSL programs are too.

For details, see the few available Channel9 videos and WSL blog.

To the original question - how to "drop" admin privileges for running WSL, see for example [here](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/reducing-browser-privileges).

Answer (score 3):

When you install Bash on Windows the first time, you are prompted to create a (non-root) Linux account. When you start bash.exe, that is the account you are automatically logged in as.

Comment: Not as of Feb, 2017 because it is install via Windows "store"

Comment: In 2018, this seems to sometimes work, but not always. I would recommend following the old instructions, e.g. here https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-bash-shell-command-line-windows-10 That makes you e.g. manually enable the Developer mode. The image needs to be downloaded via the Store. On my second try (after uninstalling the first Ubuntu 18.04) and doing as above, I got the user creation prompt. Wish it was there, always.